# How to disable AppleUSB20HubPort@fa120000

Tags: macos, boot, macos-sierra

After installing driver for mobile modem (Huawei K36xxx) and after restart MAC it won't boot up, in boot up messages i can see that there is some kind of loop. After that i decided to load OS x from flash drive and backed up all my files but i don't want to lose my programs which i can't backup actually. So could you help me somehow disable this error or delete it ? 
The full error message you can find bellow :

> AppleUSB20HubPort@fa120000: AppleUSBHostPort::disconnect:
>   persistent enumeration failures

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does the problem still happen with all USB devices (especially the Hauwei modem) disconnected from all USB ports?

Comment: Not all USB devices, Only with Huawei Modem. But the main thing was that I've installed Huawei Modem driver from internet and probably that was harmed or it was virus. Anyway I fixed this issue by following method :
1) Boot up in Safe mode from liveCD
2) From terminal I found all the ways where Huawei mas mentioned
3) Deleted all files *huawei 
4) Reboot Mac and "Voala" Everything got back again

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Boot up in Safe mode from liveCD  2) From terminal I found all the
>   ways where Huawei mas mentioned  3) Deleted all files *huawei in /dev/
>   & /Library/ ~/Library/ 4) Reboot Mac and "Voala" Everything got back
>   again